# Subtracting values to contour map axis python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to subtract a certain value for example 50 to both axis x and y of a image contour map I would like modify the axis so they will begin  from -50 to 50. [image: contour map]

The image is overlapped with a colormap but the x and y axises correspond to the contourmap.

The code that I used to generate the contour map is basically:

```
plt.clf()
plt.figure()
ax=plt.gca()
cba=plt.colorbar()
line_colours = ('gray', 'white', 'black')
contour=plt.contour(fits_data1,origin='lower',colors=line_colours )
imgplot=plt.imshow(np.log10(array_auxiliar),origin='lower',clim=(0.0, 0.7))
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(15.0, 20.0), width=b_maj,height=b_min,angle=bpa,edgecolor='b', fc='b', lw=2,fill=True)
ax.add_patch(ellipse)
cba.ax.set_ylabel('$log_{10}(F(Ha))$',labelpad = 15,fontsize = 15)
plt.show()
```

Here 'fits_data1' is my first image array plotted with the contour map and 'array_auxiliar' is the image overlapped beneath the contour map and which data are related to the colorbar.

'fits-data1' is a 2x2 array and i tried to substract 50 to each index [i] and [j] but I really dont see what could be a possible solution to make x and y axes go from -50 to 50. The idea is that the (0,0) point in the image correspond to the image center.

Thanks!

Comment: No just the x and y axis of the map ( 0 to 100 )

Comment: I have made some modifications to the original post, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=contour#matplotlib.pyplot.contour), if you don't supply the coordinates for the surface, they will be chosen automatically for you. You have `plt.contour(Z)` and you want `plt.contour(X, Y, Z)`. To achieve this, use [`numpy.meshgrid()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html), which even has an example for `plt.contour()`.

```
x = np.linspace(-50, 50, fits_data1.shape[0])
y = np.linspace(-50, 50, fits_data1.shape[1])
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.contour(X, Y, fits_data1, origin='lower', colors=line_colours)
```

Minor tidbit, [`numpy.linspace()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) generates evenly spaced data in the range [start, stop] (inclusive). This can produce different numbers than using `np.arange()`, so it's up to you which one you want.

```
>>> np.linspace(-5, 5, 10)
array([-5.        , -3.88888889, -2.77777778, -1.66666667, -0.55555556,
        0.55555556,  1.66666667,  2.77777778,  3.88888889,  5.        ])
>>> np.linspace(-5, 5, 10, endpoint=False)
array([-5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
>>> np.arange(-5, 5, 1.)
array([-5., -4., -3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
```